# When to choose type `{}` over `object` or does it matter?

Tags: typescript

I am wondering about the (semantic) difference in Typescript between `{}` and `object`.

For example if you have a function which accepts an object, but you do not know or care about its shape, would you declare it as `{}` or `object` or does it not matter?

Here's an example:

```
export async function updateSomeUserData(
  userId: string,
  data: object
): Promise<void> {
  const ref = await getUserDataRef(userId);

  await ref.update({
    ...data
  });
}
```

I real life you might want to strictly define all possible data properties with optional keys in a type, but I think this kind of situation can happen where you don't want to be so specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is quite subtle:

- Something typed as `{}` or `Object` can represent any object.
- Something typed as `object` can only represent non-primitive types - in other words, it cannot be a `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `null` or `undefined`.

In both cases, using the `obj.member` syntax will only allow you to access the members of the `Object` prototype.

This is what makes `{}` and `Object` differ from the `any` type - the latter doesn't give you any type safety, while the former will only give you type safety for `Object` prototype members.

To access an arbitrary key, you have to use the `obj["member"]` syntax, which effectively tells the type system 'I won't know if this member exists until runtime`. As such, you should make sure to null check it!

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer! I was _not_ expecting {} to represent any object. Good point about the alternative syntax too.

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman: Yeah, it's not massively intuative at first glance - the reason `{}` is valid for any object is because TypeScript is ['structurally typed'](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) - a type with no members is effectively a subset of every other type.